# Datanucleus enhancer claims that no files to run

Tags: maven, jdo, datanucleus

I have Maven project which is basically almost a copy of Datanucleus demo project. When I run Maven install in Eclipse for my project, it sometimes runs enhancer, which is what I except to happend everytime I run maven install. But for some unknown reason, it sometimes says following.

```
[INFO] --- maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.2.0-m1:enhance (default) @ my.datanucleus.dao ---
[WARNING] No files to run DataNucleus tool 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer'
```

I have no other warnings or errors in my Maven log. Am I doing something wrong or why is this happening, because it is very annoying, because my package will not work if classes are not enhanced.

Comment: The DN enhancer is a java process that requires input. If there is no input then it will return that. So trace backwards to what is passed in to the DN Maven2 plugin, so that it has some input. You provide no detail of your project, or what input you're providing to it. Obviously the log at DEBUG level provides more detail

Comment: Well project is similar to Datanucleus example project. It is using MySQL. Usually problem is fixed, if I run Eclipse Project Clean, but not always. Debug level did not show anything extra.

Comment: so log your problem against the "m2e" Eclipse plugin which is presumably what you're using, since the DataNucleus project only provides a Maven plugin (which works, in that there are no issues against it), and its own Eclipse plugin (which also works, ditto).

Comment: I'm also encountering this despite it happening everytime via terminal mvn command.
` [INFO] --- datanucleus-maven-plugin:4.0.1:enhance (default-cli) @ MyServerProject ---
[WARNING] No files to run DataNucleus tool 'org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer'`